# Two do while loop

Tags: java, sql, arrays, vector

The two do while loop are really confusing me..

I have created a function used to do matching with the number in sql. If the user input value exists, it will add 1. The `(Object[] array)` holding user input values and compare with the value in sql. There are two rows in sql.
The program should be works like this:

```
(Object[] array) // assuming it holds
[2,3]

Object[] array1 // holding 
[1,2,3,0,0] and [2,5,6,0,0]

Output : 2 1
```

But I can't get any output...What's wrong with my code?

**I pretty sure the error comes from  CountMatching(Object[] array, Object[] array1)**

```
public void ComparePre(Object[] array) throws Exception {
    String sql="Select Pre1,Pre2,Pre3,Pre4,Pre5 from preferences ";
    DatabaseConnection db = new DatabaseConnection();
    Connection  conn =db.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement  ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
    Object[] b=new Object[5];
    while (rs.next()) {  
        Vector r = new Vector();   // sql data to vector
        r.add(rs.getInt("Pre1"));
        r.add(rs.getInt("Pre2"));
        r.add(rs.getInt("Pre3"));
        r.add(rs.getInt("Pre4"));
        r.add(rs.getInt("Pre5"));
        System.out.println(r);
        Object[] array1 = new Object[5];
        r.copyInto(b);
    }
    CountMatching(array,b); 
    ps.close();
    rs.close();
    conn.close();
}

private void CountMatching(Object[] array, Object[] array1) {
    int count=0;
    int a=0;
    do {
        int b=0;
        do {
            if(array[a]==array1[b]) {
                count++;
            } else if(array[a]!=array1[b]) {
                b++;
            }
        } while(b<array1.length);
        a++;
    } while (a<array.length);
    System.out.println(count);     
}
```

Comment: What is this trying to do? What are you comparing?

Comment: I want to compare all the values in array with array1. Example: array holds [2,3] and array1 holds[1,2,3,0,0]. The index 0 in array will compare all the index in array1. After finish comparing, it will continue compare index 1 in array, and starting from index 0 in array1 again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see at least two problems with this method:

1. The two nested `do { ... } while ()` loops might end up in an infinite loop. That is, if `array[a]==array1[b]` is true at any time, the internal counter `b` will never be increased (i.e. `b++` is never invoked).
2. if one of the arrays has the length `0`, this method will throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

In its current form, the method will only do what it is supposed to, if both arrays are not empty (length > 0) and **NO** actual match can be found.

Explicit `for` loops might prevent that, if that is what you need:

```
private void CountMatching(Object[] array, Object[] array1) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int a = 0; a < array.length; a++) {
        for (int b = 0; b < array1.length; b++) {
            if (array[a] == array1[b]) {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(count);
}
```

Or if you don't need the specific indices for anything else:

```
private void CountMatching(Object[] array, Object[] array1) {
    int count = 0;
    for (Object arrayEntry : array) {
        for (Object array1Entry : array1) {
            if (arrayEntry == array1Entry) {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(count);
}
```

---

In your current code `r.copyInto(b)` is always overwriting whatever was in the array before, so you get only the last result row:

```
Object[] b=new Object[5];
while (rs.next()) {
    Vector r = new Vector();   // sql data to vector
    r.add(rs.getInt("Pre1"));
    r.add(rs.getInt("Pre2"));
    r.add(rs.getInt("Pre3"));
    r.add(rs.getInt("Pre4"));
    r.add(rs.getInt("Pre5"));
    System.out.println(r);
    Object[] array1 = new Object[5];
    r.copyInto(b);
}
CountMatching(array,b);
```

The easiest way out would be to move `CountMatching(array,b)` up by one line (i.e. into the while loop).

Comment: I should get two count as my output because I have two rows in my sql. But I only getting the count in the second rows

Comment: @Seng You're calling the `CountMatching(Object, Object)` only once in `ComparePre(Object[])`. Consequently you get only one output.

Comment: The ComparePre(Object) holding user's input which used to compare the value in sql..All the values in sql had been stored in variable b in ComparePre function.

Comment: @Seng move `CountMatching(array,b)` into the `while (rs.next())` loop. It currently only compares the last result row's values.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you could do it with `int[]` (and avoid the `Vector`). Also, I would recommend [`for-each` loops](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) and [`try-with-resources`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). Something like,

```
static void countMatching(int[] a, int[] b) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i : a) {
        for (int j : b) {
            if (i == j) {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.printf("The matching count is %d%n", count);
}

public void comparePre(int[] array) throws Exception {
    String sql = "Select Pre1,Pre2,Pre3,Pre4,Pre5 from preferences";
    DatabaseConnection db = new DatabaseConnection();
    try (Connection conn = db.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
        while (rs.next()) {
            int[] array1 = new int[] { rs.getInt("Pre1"),
                    rs.getInt("Pre2"), rs.getInt("Pre3"),
                    rs.getInt("Pre4"), rs.getInt("Pre5") };
            countMatching(array, array1);
        }
    }
}
```